# Android internet usage of requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, android-location

I need to know how much data we need for getting the current user location? so how many kbytes we need for every one call of request for location update or on location change ?

Comment: request updates from gps provider and you can get the location data without any data usage.

Comment: There's some info [on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-Googles-location-services-use-up-mobile-data-If-so-how-much-mobile-data-does-it-use). None or very little, apparently. I don't have a proper answer.